# How to send an e-mail from Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, smtp

I'm trying to send an e-mail from a React/Node.js application. Currently, I'm
trying to use [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) module.

The code is the following:

```
const emailjs = require('emailjs')

sendEmail(email) {
  var server    = emailjs.server.connect({
    user:    "USERNAME", 
    password:"PASSWORD", 
    host:    "HOST_URL", 
    ssl:     false
  });
  server.send({
    text:    'Message', 
    from:    '"Sender" <mail@provider.com>', 
    to:      email,
    subject: "Some message subject"
  }, 
  function(err, message) { 
    console.log(err || message); 
  });
}
```

When this method is executed, I get the following error: `net.Socket is not a constructor`.

How can I send an e-mail from a Node.JS application (using any NPM module, not necessarily emailjs)?

**Update 1 (30.07.2017 09:12 MSK):** Nodemailer doesn't work -- I get the error `09:11:03 web.1   |  Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'C:\myproject\node_modules\nodemailer\lib\mailer'`.

[image: Nodemailer error]

Comment: You need to configure the “var server” in order to connect to an email server. here I found some documents: https://github.com/eleith/emailjs

Comment: @JackLuo I already pass the mail server parameters to `emailjs.server`. What exactly may be missing?

Comment: try node-mailer :D

Comment: @thelonglqd Nodemailer doesn't work. See update 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause of the problem. Originally, the function for sending the e-mail was located inside a React component. An answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155660/cant-resolve-dns-and-child-process-when-using-nodemailer-and-webpack) said it's impossible to send an e-mail from the front end.

So I moved the e-mail sending routine into `server.js` and now the original error disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I use nodemailer to send emails and just love how simple it is.

This is the website to that module: https://nodemailer.com/about/

It has all the examples that you can follow
Below is an example I got from w3school. I always use this and works like charm. Depends on what kind of email you use (gmail, hotmail, outlook,...), make proper changes and you're good

```
var nodemailer = require('nodemailer');

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  service: 'gmail',
  auth: {
    user: 'youremail@gmail.com',
    pass: 'yourpassword'
  }
});

var mailOptions = {
  from: 'youremail@gmail.com',
  to: 'myfriend@yahoo.com',
  subject: 'Sending Email using Node.js',
  text: 'That was easy!'
};

transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function(error, info){
  if (error) {
    console.log(error);
  } else {
    console.log('Email sent: ' + info.response);
  }
});
```

Comment: Please post the actual request you sent, just fake or cross out all confidential info. And can you check if node-mailer is installed successfully? Also, are your behind any proxy?

Comment: I couldn't send the request because Node.js won't start.

Answer (score 0):

Hi @DP_ and everyone.-

I had succesfuly implemented nodemailer, thanks to you also, i had the same DNS error and moved the Send function to server.js and that helped me a lot. However to make it work with Nodemailer i used Hapi.js and also xoauth2 becouse i want to send a custom e-mail through gmail, which is very important for me. You need to configure Xoauth2 first at Google Api and add the api's to your account first, then wait some time till your refreshToken is approved and add it to your app. And that is in short what i did, hope this helps somebody becouse it took me some time to get it working.